# Add handler to the images in RichTextBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox, handler

In the Silverlight , we can insert an image in a [RichTextBox](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/index.htm#/?sref=RichNotepadSnippets) by using a InlineUIContainer.
Now I'm trying to add some handlers to this image. Here is my code:

```
InlineUIContainer contain = new InlineUIContainer();
Image image = new Image();
ImageSource img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Source,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, img);
image.MouseEnter +=new MouseEventHandler(image_MouseEnter);
container.Child = image;
rtb.Selection.Insert(contain);
```

However, when we move our mouse enter this image, nothing happen.
What I'm trying to add are some handlers like resize, click, and drag and drop. Is it possible?
I appreciate for any answers. Thanks!

Comment: It's already half month...Any comment is welcome please...

Comment: I'm currently researching something of a similar problem. This *might* be happening here as well. [MSDN for UIElement.MouseWheel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousewheel(v=VS.95).aspx) under version notes, it states "Silverlight 4 has controls that have specific control handling for MouseWheel, which means that in certain cases your user code event handlers are not invoked, because the control marks the event as handled. You can still handle these cases, but you must specifically attach the handler with AddHandler and handledEventsToo as true." Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, I came up with a new solution to my same problem last night. I check out if I'm clicking (RTB_OnLeftMouseDown) on one of my images based on looping through all images in the BlockControl and looking at the block control's viewRect. Then I go into ReadOnly mode while I resize until I click off of the image again (go back to edit mode). This allows me to put little resize adorners onto the image and get all of the mouse events on the image. It's a pretty complicated solution though, so you might want to go a different route.

Comment: Thanks very much shane! Your answer is helpful. I agree that we have to add the click event into RTB and think of some strategies locating the image we try to click. I will try your solution later.

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing happens is because in EDIT mode (IsReadOnly == false) on a richtextbox no events fire inside the richtextbox. You can get around this but it's complicated. You put the event handlers on the RichTexTBox, then you get the visual rectangle of the images in the richtextbox and see if the mouse event args point is inside a image.

Edit better explanation of why you can't: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/224490/541921.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The FlowDocument of RichTextBoxes is disabled, hence no events are processed, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684028/controls-in-inlineuicontainer-blockuicontainer-always-disabled-in-richtextbox-d) of mine for more info and a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks H.B. In my application I didn;t use FlowDocument.

Comment: H.B. This is a silverlight question, you can't touch flowdocument in silverlight. (I can add comments to other users NOW)

Comment: @shane: Oh well, there's way too much stuff you currently cannot do in Silverlight, I'll try to check again next time...