# Controls in InlineUIContainer & BlockUIContainer always disabled in RichTextBox.Document

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

For example if i have code like the following both Buttons are disabled:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <BlockUIContainer>
            <Button Content="!"/>
        </BlockUIContainer>
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Button Content="!"/>
            </InlineUIContainer>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

I have no idea why this is the case or what i can do to prevent this, obviously disabled buttons are not very useful so any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

**Edit:** It turns out that the FlowDocument gets disabled for some reason, however i have not found a way to reenable it yet, since it changes back to `IsEnabled="False"` immediately...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually is a property called [`IsDocumentEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isdocumentenabled.aspx) (.NET 3.5 onwards) on the `RichTextBox` itself that can be set to true to enable the document.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to make your custom flowdocument and override its IsEnabledCore property. Check this link out - http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/01/18/When-I-add-Controls-to-a-WPF-RichTextBox-They-Are-Always-Disabled-How-can-I-change-that.aspx

```
class EnabledFlowDocument : FlowDocument
{
    protected override bool IsEnabledCore
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's probably something i will never actually use, since you are not supposed to do it (otherwise it would not be disabled in the first place) In fact, it just ironically crashed my application with a stack-overflow exception :)